# How to initialize credential in google drive api by java?

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I have a JS page which is the google picker, it can let user select him file to upload to me. After that I can get a file Id, for the backend side, I need to make a request to send this id back to me right?  and if i want to download this file I can use the code below:

```
private static InputStream downloadFile(Drive service, File file) {
        if (file.getDownloadUrl() != null && file.getDownloadUrl().length() > 0) {
          try {
            HttpResponse resp =
                service.getRequestFactory().buildGetRequest(new GenericUrl(file.getDownloadUrl()))
                    .execute();
            return resp.getContent();
          } catch (IOException e) {
            // An error occurred.
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
          }
        } else {
          // The file doesn't have any content stored on Drive.
          return null;
        }
      }
```

In this code I need to initialize the Drive, and Drive need Credential. The code below:

```
GoogleCredential credentials = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
    .setClientSecrets(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET)
    .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory).setTransport(transport).build()
    .setRefreshToken("<REFRESH_TOKEN>").setAccessToken("<ACCESS_TOKEN>");
```

I want to know what is  and  How can I get it?